# jQuery ajax not displaying data from php to a table with angularjs and json

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, angularjs

I'm trying to display some data from a database to my html page with angular and json, but the browser even if manage to read my db doesn't show my data. Can someone explain why is this appening?

I watched several answers on this website but none managed to solve the problem, even switching from different browsers and from unix to windows.

this is my controller

```
myApp.controller('postCtrl',function($scope){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: './webservices/post.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response){
                $scope.locali = response.info;  
                $scope.posts = response.info;
                console.log($scope.locali); 
        }, 
        fail: function(result){
            $("#messaggiodierrore").html("query non riuscita! ");
        }



    });
        console.log($scope.locali);

});
```

this is my html

```
<div class="col-md-8" ng-controller = "postCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Locale </th>
          <th>Indirizzo</th>
          <th>città</th>
          <th>attrezzature</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody >
        <tr ng-repeat="locale in locali track by $index" >
          <td>{{locale.nomeLocale}}   </td>
          <td>{{locale.indirizzo}}    </td> 
          <td>{{locale.citta}}        </td>
          <td>{{locale.attrezzature}} </td>
          <td><a class="btn btn-default" href="#!rispondi">Rispondi</a>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody> 
    </table>
</div>
```

and this is my php  (that is working)

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');

$sql= "SELECT * FROM locale";

$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $locale = $row['NomeLocale'];
        $indirizzo = $row['indirizzo'];
        $citta = $row['citta'];
        $attrezzature = $row['attrezzature'];
        $result[] = array('nomeLocale'=>$locale, 'indirizzo'=>$indirizzo,'citta'=>$citta,'attrezzature'=>$attrezzature);
    } 
    $json = array('info'  => json_encode($result));

} else {
    $json = array('status'=> 0, 'msg' =>'nessun locale trovato');

}
    mysqli_close($conn);
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

the google chrome console send me this:

> [{"nomeLocale":"asdf","indirizzo":"asdf","citta":"asdf","attrezzature":"0"}]

that is what is inside my DB but i cant' understand why this is not showing in my table on html.`

Comment: please share angular js full code

Comment: Use the AngularJS $http service. The jQuery `.ajax` method is not integrated with the AngularJS framework. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular provides two different APIs to handle Ajax requests. They are

- $resource (higher level interactions with server)
- $http (lower level interactions with server)

Create new module and setup AJAX request in controller ( postCtrl ).

**Path** – Passing file name "your url" in url and set method to get.

**Success** – AJAX successfully callback handle by then where store reponse.infoto $scope.locali

At HTML end display data using ng-repeat directive.

Try this:

```
<script>
var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);

fetch.controller('postCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
 $http({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'webservices/post.php'
 }).then(function successCallback(response) {
  // Store response data
  $scope.locali = response.info;
 });
}]);

</script>
```

Comment: ok, now i updated my controller with your code, the browser's console is not showing me anything. in the panel network > response i see that it sees the string i want to display on the table but that's still not happening

Comment: it will only show the response in the console, when you add `console.log($scope.locali);`